# Margin and padding using em

Tags: css, margin, font-size

When 1em is applied to an element, it takes the default value of the browser (usually, 16px) or the font-size value of its parent, right?. But I noticed that if I use something like `margin-top: 1em` in a `h1` element (without using a reset stylesheet, and therefore, h1 is set to `font-size: 32px`), then 1em is equal to `32px`, even if its parent element is set to `font-size: 16px`.

However, using something like font-size: 100%; solves the discrepancy.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your browser? Would you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Chrome 17 stable, and checked in Firefox also.

Comment: a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855173/6908282) also talks how 1em could be different for `h1` and `h2`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> When 1em is applied to an element, it takes the default value of the browser (usually, 16px) or the font-size value of its parent, right?

No, it takes *its own* `font-size`, computed *based on its parent* (or the default browser-supplied value). Since the browser-supplied `font-size` of `h1` is 32 pixels, the resultant margin is 32 pixels.

> However, using something like font-size: 100%; solves the discrepancy.

By setting `font-size: 100%;` or `font-size: 1em;` on an element, you're telling it to use 100% of the font size of its parent, so setting `1em` as a length on anything else will follow that 100%.

Comment: Oh, well, then it's based on its inherited value. That explains it!

Comment: It's based on its computed value, rather than its inherited value. There's a subtle difference :)

Comment: @BoltClock can you expand on this a little further please? I had a similar understanding that em is calculated based on the browser default font size of 16 pixels. Citations to W3 would be great too.

Comment: @Robert Rocha: The em unit is relative to the element's font-size, unless you are specifying font-size itself, in which case it's based on its parent's font-size. The browser default for h1 is 2em, which changes depending on its parent but if you have an HTML document containing nothing but an h1 element, the default sizes of body and html are 16px making h1 32px. If your h1 were in a div with font-size: 2em, this 2em would be doubled and the size would be 64px.

Answer (score 11):

`1em` is equal to the font-size of the **element in question**. So when using it with margins, it will be equivalent to the font-size of the element you're applying the margin too.