# Adding margin-left to H1 and H2 tags

Tags: html, css

I've never seem to have this problem before, but why don't the H1 and H2 elements align evenly on the left when I specifically apply margin-left to them?

Here is the problem code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div h1,
h2 {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h1>Inspector Clouseau</h1>
   <h2>Reporting for duty</h2>
</div>
```

But when I apply margin-left to the div tag they align perfectly as I would expect?

Here is the working code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Inspector Clouseau</h1>
    <h2>Reporting for duty</h2>
</div>
```

I'm not understanding why this happens.

Comment: In first example you used `div h1, h2 {...}` - you needed `div h1, div h2 {...}`

Comment: This happens because `h1` and `h2` element have different default font sizes. You use 1em to measure the padding. `1em` = the current font size. So `h1` gets `34px` left padding while `h2` only gets `24px`

Comment: do you want Font size should be different for both the tag...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Em` values are probably the most difficult values to wrap the ol' noodle around, probably because the very concept of them is abstract and arbitrary. Here's the scoop: `1em` is equal to the current `font-size` of the element in question. If you haven't set font size anywhere on the page, then it would be the browser default, which is probably `16px`. So by default `1em` = `16px`. If you were to go and set a font-size of `20px` on your body, then `1em` = `20px`.

https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

In your code,

`h1` and `h2` have **different** font-size.

When you write the code like this

```
h1, h2{
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

It means

```
h1{
  margin-left: 40px;
}
h2{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That's very interesting, I had no idea that using em would affect them this way.

Comment: @Synthz It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
div h1,h2{
 margin-left:3%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div>
   <h1>Inspector Clouseau</h1>
   <h2>Reporting for duty</h2>
   </div>
  </header>
  <main>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

instead of using em you can use appropriate "%".
cause of font size output of h1 and h2 tag are different, so by setting margin in % will give desire output,

Answer (score 2):

`h1` and `h2` have different *font-size* property (2em for `h1` and `1.5em` for `h2` in Chrome for instance) and when you give `margin-left` as 1em it evaluates to different values in *pixels* for `h1` and `h2`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div:not(.second) h1, div:not(.second) h2 {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

div.second {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>Inspector Clouseau</h1>
      <h2>Reporting for duty</h2>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="second">
      <h1>Inspector Clouseau</h1>
      <h2>Reporting for duty</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not any issue in your apply css, but its simple things is you are use `em` unit in css.

**What is `em` unit? How it work check below ans.**

"Relative to the font-size of the element (`2em` means **2 times the size** of the current font)"

It means `h1` and `h2` font size are different so em make space different. try to put `h3` check result.